# Find function given recurence

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I have to find $f(x)$ knowing these facts:

1) $f(0) = \frac {1}{e}$.

2) $f(x) - f(\frac {x}{e}) = x ,\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$.

First I tried to give  $x$ values like: $x\leftarrow \frac xe$ or $x\leftarrow ex$, but my guess is to find a way to get $f(0)$ in the equation without simply attributing $x = 0$ because that would kill the equation.

Comment: Try $(f \circ ln) (x) $ for $x>0$

Comment: @MaxFt Nevermind I solved it.

Comment: How? With a linear function?

Comment: @MaxFt I am now posting the answer, wait 5 mins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it.

I said that:

if $$f(x) - f(\frac x{e}) = x$$

then:

$$f(\frac xe)-f(\frac {x}{e^{2}})=\frac {x}{e}$$

$$f(\frac {x}{e^{2}})-f(\frac {x}{e^{3}})=\frac {x}{e^{2}}$$

$$f(\frac {x}{e^{2}})-f(\frac {x}{e^{3}})=\frac {x}{e^{2}}$$

$$...$$

$$f(\frac {x}{e^{n-1}})-f(\frac {x}{e^{n}})=\frac {x}{e^{n-1}}$$

Now, if we add them up, we get:

$f(x) - f(\frac {x}{e^{n}})= x(1 + e + e^{2} + ... + e^{n-1})$

Using geometric progession and limit to infinity, we get:

$f(x) - f(0) = x \frac {e}{e-1}$

Using the fact that $f(0) = \frac 1e$ we get:

$$f(x) = \frac {e^{2}x+e-1}{e(e-1)}.$$

Sorry for bothering with the question I should think a bit more about it then to ask it.

Comment: Nicely done. You assumed that f was continuous to take the limit thought. Nvm it is pretty easy to show that f is continuous. I also very often find my answers while writing a post. ^^

Comment: @MaxFt Thanks, $f$ is continuous that is a given from the original question but I forgot to add it in my post.... but it's still easy to show that $f$ is continuous. That's nice.